# Sum IF, Index Matching formula not working as intended

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wps

[image]

[Copy Table Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DoRjcDf_1S2FXGAXHAhWUv-eibAAlV1msLkkv8UsBKg/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to sum numbers based on hourly and per line. I want create a summary table below for each line hourly total output.
The formula I have entered in Cell `B36` is `=SUMIF($E$2:$L$2,"="&B35,INDEX($E$3:$L$9,MATCH($A36,$A$3:$A$9,0),0))` But its showing me 0 instead of 15 for 1st hour, 60 for 2 Hour, 20 for 3 Hour, 45+37 for 4th Hour, and so on.

I would really appreciate if you guys tell me what i did wrong? or what I can do to fix this.

Comment: The formula is working as it is intended to be, formula was not aware you had merged cells and you needed the second row of data for the one those are merged. The data structure is not right, it is not recommended. Using of merged is highly not suggested and the reason you are facing already.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya
 What would you advice on the data structure. How can i improve this? Also I have tried unmerging as well, It still does not work.

Comment: Remove merged cells first and create a proper tabular data, where you can easily use the `SUMIFS()`. Its not only about unmerging, the `line #` are duplicates. You need to have some unique `line #`. Ofcourse you can use complicated formulas, but isn;t it easy to use simple formulas to work with.

Comment: I get your point, I cant think of any other way because each line might have more than one machine which changes everyday. That's why I wanted to create a formula so that  I can make a summary for each line number. The formula should add all the numbers which consists within Line 1 for each hour.

Comment: I understood your issue, but how would you decide that you need the second one for each duplicates? say for example if there is more than two `line #` which row will you be taking `2nd` or `3rd`?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I want to sum both to one cell basically. 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: So basically you are always ignoring the first one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253734/discussion-between-rohannair-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B36`

```
=SUM(
    FILTER(
        FILTER(
            $E$3:$L$28,
            SCAN(
                $A$3:$A$28,
                $A$3:$A$28,
                LAMBDA(x, y,
                    IF(
                        y = "",
                        x,
                        y
                    )
                )
            ) = $A36
        ),
        B$35 = $E$2:$L$2
    )
)
```

---

You can also use a single dynamic array formula here as well using `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B36`

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A36:A47,LAMBDA(a,b,
VSTACK(a,BYCOL(B35:I35,LAMBDA(c,
SUM(FILTER(FILTER(E3:L28,
SCAN($A$3:$A$28,$A$3:$A$28,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y)))=b,""),c=E2:L2,""))))))),1)
```